# oracle pl/sql DBMS_LOCK error

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the Oracle PL/SQL, I want to test the sleep function. I am using hr schema. but it gives me error :

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_LOCK' must be declared
```

code:

```
begin
 DBMS_LOCK.Sleep( 60 );
end;
/
```

Comment: There seems to be an easy fix in Oracle 18c: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72871986/5576771. Use `sys.dbms_session.sleep(...)` instead of `dbms_lock.sleep(...)`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should [grant execute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm) on that package to your schema

```
grant execute on <object> to <user>;
```

e.g.

```
connect as sys
grant execute on SYS.DBMS_LOCK to someuser;
```

Comment: connect as SYS user.  grant execute on SYS.DBMS_LOCK to USERNAME;

Comment: I know this post is ancient, but the issue seems to have been fixed in Oracle 18c: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72871986/5576771. Use `sys.dbms_session.sleep(...)` instead of `dbms_lock.sleep(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

If you you don't have access to sys or your dba is unwilling to do

```
   GRANT EXECUTE on SYS.DBMS_LOCK to you;
```

You can create a Java procedure in the database:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SLEEPIMPL (P_MILLI_SECONDS IN NUMBER) 
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)';
```

And create a function, which calls the java stored procedure

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sleep (
    seconds IN NUMBER
   ) RETURN NUMBER
   AS
   BEGIN
     SLEEPIMPL( seconds );
     RETURN seconds;
   END;
```

which after a

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sleep TO public;
```

you can call from a select

```
select sleep(6000) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

> [DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP Replaces DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP in Oracle Database
> 18c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/dbms_session-sleep-18c)
>
> The SLEEP procedure is added to the DBMS_SESSION package and
> deprecated from the DBMS_LOCK package in Oracle Database 18c.
>
> The SLEEP procedure is added to the DBMS_SESSION package, so it is
> available to all sessions with no additional grants needed and no
> dependency on the DBMS_LOCK package.

---

**Fails:** `dbms_lock.sleep(...)`

```
with function slow_function(p_id  in number) return number
    deterministic as
begin
    dbms_lock.sleep(0.02);  --look here
    return p_id;
end;

select 
    slow_function(level)
from 
    dual
connect by level <= 20000
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "SYS"."DBMS_LOCK": invalid identifier
```

---

**Succeeds:** `sys.dbms_session.sleep(...)`

```
with function slow_function(p_id  in number) return number
    deterministic as
begin
    --dbms_lock.sleep(0.02);
    sys.dbms_session.sleep(0.02);  --look here
    return p_id;
end;

select 
    slow_function(level)
from 
    dual
connect by level <= 20000
```

Result:

```
SLOW_FUNCTION(LEVEL)
--------------------
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
                   1
…
10 rows of 20000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c60b241a1720f1e1b32befe89bbfae91)

Related: [Why does DETERMINISTIC function return unexpected numbers in CONNECT BY LEVEL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72871656/why-does-deterministic-function-return-unexpected-numbers-in-connect-by-level-qu)

---

*I'm not an expert, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

Self made procedure. If you dont have the right to set the grant

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure new_sleep(p_nSekunden  number)

is

  dDate  date := sysdate;
begin

  if p_nSekunden < 1 then
    return;
  end if;
 
  dDate := dDate + ( (1/24/3600) * p_nSekunden );

  loop
    exit when sysdate > dDate;       
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem and my user did not get access on DBMS_LOCK package and as I am currently on 12c so cannot use `DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP` package. So created the following procedure to accommodate wait time of 30 minutes.

Parameter ***V_START_DATE*** saves' current datetime.

Parameter ***V_END_DATE*** saves' current datetime and adds the number of minutes you want your job to wait (in this case 30/1440 adds 30 minutes).

***WHILE*** loop will iterate till the end datetime, and will break if the flag is 1 or the execution exceeds the wait time specified (i.e V_END_DATE > V_START_DATE) and flag value <> 1.

```
create or replace procedure SP_SLEEP_ALTERNATE is
  V_FLAG       INT := 0;
  V_START_DATE DATE;
  V_END_DATE   DATE;
begin

  SELECT SYSDATE INTO V_START_DATE FROM DUAL;

  SELECT SYSDATE + 30 / 1440 INTO V_END_DATE FROM DUAL;

  while V_START_DATE <= V_END_DATE LOOP
  
    BEGIN
      /* get flag from a table */
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        V_FLAG := 0;
    END;
    IF V_FLAG <> 1 THEN
    
      V_FLAG := 0;
    ELSIF V_FLAG = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Execution Started');
      EXIT;
    ELSIF V_FLAG <> 1 AND V_START_DATE > V_END_DATE THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  
    SELECT SYSDATE INTO V_START_DATE FROM DUAL;
  
  END LOOP;

end SP_SLEEP_ALTERNATE;
```

I hope it helps someone, facing the same issue.