# How to validate entries to oracle raw column

Tags: java, oracle, raw

I have a requirement where before entry to a raw column, first the data needs to be validated in Java. I guess what I need is a hex validation?.

I saw some approaches in  [Verify if String is hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424540/verify-if-string-is-hexadecimal)

But wanted to know if there are any libraries or (Since the above question is pretty old) options available in newer versions of Java that does this, specifically a solution which does not fail due to the size of the String, for eg, Long.parseLong can fail if it is found to be beyond the Long range

Comment: you can use `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2` to validate the raw as string

Comment: Do you want to verify in java code or in Oracle database? Wasn't RAW data-type replaced with LOB (Large OBject) as in BLOB or CLOB?

Comment: @Abra in Java code. I have situation where I need to deal with RAW

Comment: If you want only Java, the `oracle` tag should be removed from the question

Comment: It is to check entry into an oracle raw column.

Comment: Oracle triggers can be written in Java and executed in the built-in JVM in Oracle, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54727938/4178262 for example.